# Postgres Large array import

Tags: postgresql, csv

I just received a large data array of random numbers. 20 numbers per line, 600,000 lines in a CSV file. The numbers are separated by a space instead of a comma thus postgresql reads it as one long string per line and I cannot insert the proper data attribute for the data.

Each set of numbers will have a unique id. Each number is 2 digits long. I want the ability to count the amount of times a certain number was entered. Get the frequency of each number between certain ID's.

My question:

- What data type should I use to insert the data so it is recognized as integers instead of text?
- How do I replace the space with a comma?
- Do I need to replace the space with a comma?

Currently running Postgres 9.6, PgAdmin 4.
Bonus if answer is provided in PgAdmin as well.

Also here is a sample

Excel
Numbers

06 18 20 21 24 32 36 40 44 47 50 52 55 57 60 61 62 68 72 79

03 05 12 13 14 16 17 18 24 28 33 34 35 39 44 55 62 63 64 67

09 10 12 13 15 25 30 31 36 42 43 44 46 48 51 57 65 69 75 79

08 12 15 20 27 33 34 37 41 43 44 45 54 55 60 61 66 70 72 76

CSV FILE

Numbers06 18 20 21 24 32 36 40 44 47 50 52 55 57 60 61 62 68 72 79
03 05 12 13 14 16 17 18 24 28 33 34 35 39 44 55 62 63 64 67
09 10 12 13 15 25 30 31 36 42 43 44 46 48 51 57 65 69 75 79
08 12 15 20 27 33 34 37 41 43 44 45 54 55 60 61 66 70 72 76

or the file with the id numbers
 CSV
ID, Numbers
1253842,06 18 20 21 24 32 36 40 44 47 50 52 55 57 60 61 62 68 72 79
1253843,03 05 12 13 14 16 17 18 24 28 33 34 35 39 44 55 62 63 64 67
1253844,09 10 12 13 15 25 30 31 36 42 43 44 46 48 51 57 65 69 75 79
1253845,08 12 15 20 27 33 34 37 41 43 44 45 54 55 60 61 66 70 72 76
1253846,04 06 07 09 11 12 13 14 18 20 21 26 30 36 37 41 43 48 74 79
1253847,01 11 14 15 35 37 38 43 46 48 49 51 53 57 64 65 66 70 76 77
1253848,01 03 14 17 20 22 24 25 38 42 46 54 56 57 60 61 66 72 78 80

Here's the error message
>

> ERROR:  malformed array literal: "06 18 20 21 24 32 36 40 44 47 50 52 55 57 60 61 62 68 72 79"
>   DETAIL:  Array value must start with "{" or dimension information.
>   CONTEXT:  COPY Quick numbers, line 2, column numbers : "06 18 20 21 24 32 36 40 >44 47 50 52 55 57 60 61 62 68 72 79"

Comment: I think what you need to do is replace space serapator using vim/ or sed command (if you are using linux).  
in vim:
open file, press escape then type :%s/ /,/g
then escape and :wq

This will replace all spaces to commas. 

Then you run \copy table_name from 'path_to_file' delimiter "," csv;

Comment: If you could give me an example that would be great. Im awful at SQL Shell but I'm willing to try anything. Please expand on your answer.

Comment: Are you using linux or windows?

Comment: LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE  '/path_to_my_file.csv' INTO TABLE your_table_name FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' ENCLOSED BY '"';

Comment: I'm using windows 10.

Comment: give the table definition please